# Increasing Amplification using a MAXIM MAX492 Op Amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm using a Maxim DAC (the MAX541) with a TI microcontroller.  I output a digital audio signal from the microcontroller to the DAC.  I have the DAC's output hooked up to a typical 3.5mm audio jack.  When I plug the 3.5mm jack into typical computer speakers the volume is quite low.  I have to crank up the speakers to hear the audio.

Hooking up the 3.5mm audio jack to my oscilloscope I see the max peak-to-peak voltage output is only about 0.12 volts:

[image]

When I play the same digital audio using my phone at a reasonably loud level and analyze it with my oscilloscope I see the peak-to-peak max voltage is around 1 volt:

[image]

When purchasing the MAX541 DAC I suspected it would need some amplification so I also purchased a MAX492 op amp.  I have the analog output of the DAC going to the input exactly as shown in the MAX492 datasheet's "typical operating circuit" example:

[image: MAX492 typical operating circuit]

[Here's a link to the MAX492 datasheet](https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX492-MAX495.pdf).

However, this is only amplifying the signal to a peak-to-peak max of about 0.23 volts.  I of course need the MAX492 to amplify the signal to around 1 volt (like my phone's output level), however, I've read through the datasheet and it's not clear to me how to do this or if it's even possible.

Any help would be most appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to get more than 150mV out of the DAC - what are you supplying to Vref?

Comment: I'm supplying 2.5V to Vref.  The TI microcontroller is a TM4C1294G dev board.  It has a 5V power pin.  I use a voltage divider to get 2.5V.

Comment: Have you got decoupling on the divider?  Perhaps check the actual divider voltage in case the DAC is loading it.

Comment: @Frog - Hi, I really appreciate the help and am very eager to learn more, please pardon my ignorance, but can you explain what you mean by "decoupling on the divider"?  I just Googled "decouple voltage divider" and it didn't turn up much pertinent info.

Comment: Sure, I’m happy to help.  Decoupling is where you place a capacitor in parallel with one of the resistors in a divider, typically between ground and, in this case, the 2.5V.  This has the effect of reducing the effective impedance of the divider at high frequencies.  In other words, if the DAC suddenly applies a load to the divider, the voltage that it presents won’t change immediately.  However, if the DAC loads the divider constantly it won’t help, and you’ll need a better way to produce Vref, such as a regulator or a divider followed by a buffer.

Comment: @Frog - Thanks for the info.  Here's an image of my DAC circuit: https://i.ibb.co/c8bQDxz/daccircuit.png  There's actually two capacitors in parallel with the resistor in the divider going to ground.  So, would you agree this is decoupled?

Comment: Looks good - 330R is a relatively low resistance so should hold up against a DC load too.  That aside, do you know whether the digital source is using the full range?  If not then clearly you’re not going to get full range in analogue

Comment: @Frog - Okay, thanks for reviewing.  Yep, made sure to normalize the 16 bit audio data before converting it to the array.  A short wave file version of the audio sample I'm using is located [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmdarwen/Misc/main/TivaMAX541/Documentation/AudioSample.wav).  [Here's an image of the audio in Audacity](https://i.ibb.co/StCRrTB/Piano-Sample-Waveform.png).  One thing that I just realized is that the +5V pin from the Tiva board is, with nothing else hooked up, is only reporting +4.5V on my meter and my voltage diver shows +2.2V.  ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the voltage gain of the opamp at \$Gain = 1 + \frac{10k}{10k} = 2\$ times.
If you want the voltage gain to be 8.3 times then use 75k for the negative feedback resistor (R1 in the image below).

[image: opamp]

Comment: Hi, thank you for this information.  I'll give it a try.  I take it this is a standard equation for a non-inverting amp?  I'm a software engineer learning about electronics (with no formal training), so if so, I was not aware of this.

Comment: Thank you!  This seems to work brilliantly!  I also googled some and found this: https://circuitdigest.com/calculators/op-amp-gain-calculator with the same equation, so I assume it is indeed a standard equation for a non-inverting amp.